Rotted Subfloor / Door Flashing Advice
We recently had our old deck torn down and a new one built, as the old one was not attached to the house correctly and did not have flashing, leading to water issues. During that work, it was discovered the sliding door also does not have any flashing or sill pan underneath it, so we are still having water issues. We have a contractor that is going to replace the door properly with flashing.
My question is this - a small portion of the subfloor under the door has rotted out due to the water infiltration. To replace that rotted section we’d have to rip out about 4 kitchen floor tiles, cut out 16 inches as the joists run parallel to the door (red line on tile photo is where next joist is), screw in new section and replace tiles. Is this level of damage worth that work or should we just have the door replaced with proper flashing and call it day?
My contractor says there’s no need replace the small section of subfloor, but my worry is what will the flashing/door sit on in that small corner? Put in a piece of blocking under that section?
Pictures linked below. Any advice is welcomed. Thank you.
https://imgur.com/a/mWFl3XQ

I agree with your contractor. The subfloor does not need to be replaced.
The damage was initiated by water but done by microorganisms. Kill the organisms with a 50/50 mixture of bleach and water. Spray it on so it soaks into the wood. The wood will then be serviceable.
When dry, the hole can be filled with a patching compound like automotive body filler or Durams Rock Hard mixed very stiff. Then block under the area with a 3/4 piece of plywood and blocking between the joists at 12" spacing.
(This may be overkill, but it will stiffen the floor very well to prevent tiles from cracking.)
Nothing need be done with the finished floor tiles.

Thank you, I appreciate it. I will say the damaged wood continues a few inches out both directions from the hole. Wood is a bit soft and when dry brittle to where I can break off with my hands. With that additional info, does your answer change or should I still be good to do what you suggest after I tear out a few more inches of wood?

@Nick, tear out what is loose. Fill the hole and proceed as I suggested.
